# jest collectCoverageFrom glob string that ignores files ending with module.ts but contains *.ts

Tags: jestjs, glob

I am trying to configure `collectCoverageFrom` for jest to look up all my `.ts` files expect those with `.module.ts`  but I can not find the correct glob pattern.

As peer what I understand this should work :

```
src/**/**.!(.module.ts).ts
```

but for some reason it does not takes files like this one:

```
src/pages/home/home.ts
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use two rules `['src/**/*.ts','!**/*.module.ts']]`.

Looks like the second rule filters the first rule results: "Take all the *.ts files except(!) *.module.ts"

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
src/**/!(*module)*.ts
```

You can test this glob pattern using globster https://globster.xyz/?q=**%2F!(*module)*.ts